# React use radium to change css under div

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is my original code :

the css will change all the `p` tag under `<div className="TEST">`

**Home.js**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="TEST">
          <p>1234567</p>
          <p>1234567</p>
          <p>1234567</p>
          <a>qqqqqqqqqqqq</a>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**style.css**

```
.TEST p {
  color:#ffa;
}
```

And If I use Radium, I need to add on each `p` under `<div className="TEST">`
Is there some method I can add the style in `<div className="TEST">` just one time to change the p color like the style.css way ???

```
import Radium from 'radium';

let styles = {
  home:{
  test:{
    color:'#ffa',
  }
}

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="TEST">
          <p style={styles.test}>1234567</p>
          <p style={styles.test}>1234567</p>
          <p style={styles.test}>1234567</p>
          <a>qqqqqqqqqqqq</a>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's clear to me but I'm guessing that you are looking to dynamically add new styles to your `styles` object and then use them in your `render()` method, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if I use radium,does it means I need to add style on each tag , or is there other method that I can just set once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Style` component of Radium (see more at: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/tree/master/docs/api#style-component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Radium, { Style } from 'radium'

export default class Home extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Style scopeSelector=".TEST p" rules={{ color: '#ffa' }} />
        <div className="TEST">
          <p>1234567</p>
          <p>1234567</p>
          <p>1234567</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question. When you write component, will you use radium to replace the css files?? or you use both of them??

Comment: On my last project I've completely replaced css files for inline styles using Radium. You can keep both, though.